# How to show dialog after new selecteditem is shown in comboBox in wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

For example:I have a comboBox which has three items:AAAAA,BBBBB,CCCCC.Now the selected item is AAAAA, when I select BBBBB, selection changed event is fired. I want combobox show the current selected item (which now is BBBBB),but when messagebox show ,combobox still show AAAAA,just like the screen-shot below:

[image: The old item is AAAAA,the new item is BBBBB]

This is not what I want,I want ComboBox show BBBBB,and then the messagebox is popup. I didn't find any way to solve this problem .Can anybody help me ? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [DropDownClosed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.combobox.dropdownclosed?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) event.

Comment: it works! thank you a lot!

Comment: Hi,Jesse,if I use mvvm ,bind selected Item to viewmodel,and when selecteditem changed,there's no dropdownclose event,how can I handle this problem?

Comment: @FranklinLee: There should always be a dropdownclose event if you are selecting the combobox with your mouse. Are you saying you are changing the selecteditem programmatically? When you say `when selecteditem changed`, how is the item being changed?

Comment: :Let me clear what I said. We all know that Combbox has ItemsSource ,and SelectedItem property. So, if I bind ItemsSource to an Observable<T>（let's call it Students）,and bind SelectedItem to a instance of T(let's call it Student), then I can change combobox selectedItem by changing Student.  In such case, if I want to show a dialog after the new selected Item is shown in combobox,how can I make it ?

Comment: @FranklinLee: I'm not seeing the issue, why not show the dialog after you change Student? It might be easier to understand your problem if you make another question and show the code you are using.

Answer (score 0):

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        
        <ComboBox x:Name="cbItem" Height="20" Width="150" SelectionChanged="cbItem_SelectionChanged"></ComboBox>
    </Grid>
</Window>



using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace WpfApp
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            cbItem.Items.Add("AAAA");
            cbItem.Items.Add("BBBB");
            cbItem.Items.Add("CCCC");
        }

        private void cbItem_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var cmb = sender as System.Windows.Controls.ComboBox;
            var str = cmb.SelectedItem;
            MessageBox.Show(str.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

use selection changed event and get selected item from Combobox and print it

Comment: Thanks,but It's not what I want to solve.